# How can i fit an ellipse inside an object

Tags: image-processing

I have the following image. I want to fit ellipse into each black region. Then I want to measure the major and minor axis length. I would be grateful if any one can give me any idea. I know how to fit an ellipse over the image object.

[image: Binary Image]